# Moving email from Gmail to Mail.app locally

Tags: gmail, email

I have a large amount of email in Gmail, the account is at 99% capacity. I'd like to remove this from Gmail and only store it locally. Using mail.app When I drag the message from a Gmail mailbox into a local folder the message still appears on Gmail.

How can I move the messages locally so they don't appear in Gmail anymore?

Thanks,

Comment: How did you set up the local folder, does it appear under "Local"?

Comment: Yes, I created a mailbox on my Mac and dragged the message from a folder in gmail to the local mailbox.

Comment: Strange, when I drag stuff from Gmail->Local in Mail.app 5.1, it disappears from Gmail... I have to hold down Cmd if I want to copy it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you might need to manually delete the messages in Gmail as well. I'm not familiar with copying mail to a local folder, but I do know that Gmail is VERY protective of keeping its mail within its service as much as possible.

That would be the best advice I can offer.